# Modifying triggers of tasks with highest privileges using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script which reads a csv file of job names & triggers and then update the triggers of jobs on Task Scheduler by using Set-ScheduledTask cmdlet. I am able to update the triggers of the jobs. but few tasks are running with Highest privileges. My script is failing there saying "Access is denied"

Below is the code I using:

```
$user= "SYSTEM\serviceaccount" # Specify the account to run the script
$password="password" 

$mySettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries
$pricipalSettings= New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $user -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $taskPath -TaskName $jobName -User $user -Password $password -Trigger $TriggerFinal -Settings $mySettings
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
Set-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
At C:\UpdateTriggers.ps1:50 char:9
+         Set-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $taskPath -TaskName $jobName -Trigger $Trigg ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Set-ScheduledTask], CimException
```

Please let me know if any details are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain the `DOMAIN`, you just have to do this in the CMD: `echo %userdomain%`

This script creates a task scheduler with the highest level privileges.

```
$User= "DOMAIN\user"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $TriggerInfo
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument "-NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -File c:/Users/user/documents/script.ps1"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskScheduler" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force
```

Check this:

```
-RunLevel Highest –Force
```